# Fixing IndexError from QGIS Weights of Evidence (WofE) plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, indexerror

I am using the QGIS plugin Weights of Evidence (WofE) plugin (https://github.com/chudasama-bijal/QGIS-Plugin-Weights-of-Evidence-Model). When I perform the 'Calculate Weights' step using the Evidence Raster (generated from the 'Pre-process Data' step), I get an error saying

> 'IndexError: index 14 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 14'.

The index number (14 in this example) is different when I use rasters that have classes of different sizes (distance intervals). The raster classes are based on distance from an original raster and represent distance intervals (i.e. class 1 = 0-100m, class 2 = 100-200m, class 3 = 200-1000m, class 4 = 1000-5000m etc.).

What I have noticed is that the index number from the error is the class number for the distance interval that coincides with the 'Extent Mask Layer' (shapefile used as the extent in the WofE plugin). I have used the same raster classes on a different raster and had no issue with the plugin.

I have tried:

- Using different distance intervals for classes;
- Creating classes that stop before the boundary of the Extent Mask
  Layer;
- Re-creating he original raster, re-generating the proximity raster,
  re-classifying and re-runing the WofE plugin;
- Use Classify by Layer processing tool;
- Use Classify by Table processing tool;
- Use R.reclass GRASS processing tool.